# Create a relationship to an entity from a Dto

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs

I'm working on the backend of a system where I need a net that relates to several others but I don't do it directly from the schema as I normally would since the entity structure requires it to be done from an object that is inside. an array which is the first property of the entity.

This is an example of the json that is sent to the Mongo database, those that are marked as ObjectId are the fields that relate the entity in question with the others by the objectid

```json
{
    "mes": 9,
    "year": 2023,
    "instructor": "64ba0c41420bca285a6e261a", // ObjectId
    "eventos": [
        {
            "ficha": {
                "ficha": "64c2e63c3cc2fc659d4ef3d1", // ObjectId
                "codigo": "2362360"
            },
            "programa": {
                "nombre": "Analisis y desarrollo de software",
                "id": "64c2e2dc3cc2fc659d4ef38f" // ObjectId
            },
            "nivel": "Tecnologo",
            "municipio": "Turbo",
            "ambiente": {
                "id": "64b8758c87f48f29f890a0e7", // ObjectId
                "ambiente": "C-201"
            },
            "dia": "Lunes",
            "horario": "18:00-22:00",
            "horas": 24,
            "diainicial": 10,
            "diafinal": 24,
            "diacompleto": "10-24",
            "competencia": {
                "competencia": "DESARROLLAR LA SOLUCIÓN DE SOFTWARE DE ACUERDO CON EL DISEÑO Y METODOLOGÍAS DE DESARROLLO",
                "codigo": "12323"
            },
            "resultado": {
                "resultado": "PLANEAR ACTIVIDADES DE CONSTRUCCIÓN DEL SOFTWARE DE ACUERDO CON EL DISEÑO ESTABLECIDO",
                "orden": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to save it as a relationship in the database since the schema of my main entity is the following:

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose, { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { Instructor } from 'src/instructor/schema/instructor.schema';
import { eventosDto } from '../dto/eventos.dto';

export type EventoDocument = HydratedDocument<Evento>;

@Schema()
export class Evento {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  mes: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  year: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Instructor' })
  instructor: Instructor;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  eventos: eventosDto[];
}
export const EventoSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Evento);
```

So the only thing that is saved as a relation in the database is the first instructor field and the other fields: file.file, program.id and environment.id are saved as a normal string.

What I expect is that those fields are saved as a relationship to other entities (like the instructor case) in the database and not just plain text.

[image]